# unbind buttons: storing information only for the latest click

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a bunch of buttons (channels) and each button when clicked calls a function inside the MainController passing the ID as a parameter.

Adjacent to the channels I have a input text, where I insert information about the particular channel ID.

My requirement is to store this information with its channel ID in the DB.

In doing so, I face a small problem. When I click multiple channels one after another and then try entering the detail for the latest channel, I see that the details are inserted for all the channels that were clicked one after another. I am not sure, but somehow the channels I click, bind together. I tried using the "unbind" method. Didn't work though.

The Sample Code I use is given below:

```
Channels = ['channel1', 'channel2', 'channnel3', 'channel4']
```

### Function Call

```
<div id="grid_ch">
<button class="channel_buttons" ng-repeat="ch in Channels"  ui-sref='ChannelInfo({ch_id: ch})' ng-click='activeClickfn(ch)'>{{ ch }}</button> 
</div>
```

### Routes

```
$stateProvider.state('ChannelInfo',{
    url:'/ChannelInfo/:ch_id',
    controller: 'MainController'
    templateUrl:'/static/app/service/template/channel_info.html'
  })
```

### Main Controller

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {    
$scope.enter_info_about_channel = function() { 
    $('#info_about_channel').css({'display':'inline-block'});
};

$scope.active_clickfn;
$scope.active_clickfn = function(channel_id){
    $scope.ch_id = channel_id;
    console.log('THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS', $scope.ch_id)
    $('#info_about_channel').live('keydown', function(e){   // e is the input which is any key you press
        console.log('ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID', $scope.ch_id)
        if(e.which == 13){           
            // Insert into DB, the information about the channel here
        }
    });
}]);
```

Suppose I click the channel1, then channel2 and then channel3 and then input some information into the "enter_info_about_channel" tab then I receive the following output.

```
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel1   // After clicking button channel1
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel2   // After clicking button channel2
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel3   // After clicking button channel3

ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID channel1
ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID channel2
ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID channel3
```

However the output I desire is

```
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel1   // After clicking button channel1
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel2   // After clicking button channel2
THE CURRENT CHANNELID IS channel3   // After clicking button channel3

ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID channel3
```

The above code is somehow binding all the channels despite other channels are chosen.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Despite the fact you even be using the angular way to do this, you're using a method that is deprecated since 1.7 and it was **removed** in 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/live/ The fact is **you don't need to use jQuery to do any of this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your are coding is not angularjs style. we should not use jquery in agularjs code except in custom directives.

below is the code I have created for you. Hope it helps.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("main", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Channels..."
    $scope.channels = ["channel1", "channel2", "channel3"];
    $scope.activeChannel = null;
    $scope.channelData = "";
    $scope.logs = [];
    $scope.disableSaving = false;
    
    $scope.channelSelected = function(clicked) {
      $scope.activeChannel = clicked;
      $scope.logs.push("Clicked Channel " + clicked);
      attemptSave();
    }
    $scope.channelInfoOnBlur = function(clicked) {
      attemptSave();
    }

    var attemptSave = function() {

      if ($scope.activeChannel && $scope.channelData !== "") {
        $scope.logs.push("saving data for channel " + $scope.activeChannel + " as " + $scope.channelData);
        
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.active-button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="main">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div>

      <button class="channel_buttons" ng-class="{'active-button': activeChannel==ch}" ng-repeat="ch in channels" ui-sref='ChannelInfo({ch_id: ch})' ng-click='channelSelected(ch)'>{{ ch }}</button>
      <input placeholder="input channel info" ng-model="channelData" ng-blur="channelInfoOnBlur()" />

    </div>
    <div>Log
      <div ng-repeat="l in logs  track by $index">{{l}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AngularJS, you should be able to use the [ngKeydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown) directive and bind it to the callback.
If that isn't possible, I'd use the ['on'-method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and ['off'-method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) that jQuery has to attach and detach event-handlers.
The ['live'-method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you are using is deprecated.

```
$('#info_about_channel').off('keydown'); // remove existing keydown events
$('#info_about_channel').on('keydown', function(e){   // e is the input which is any key you press
        console.log('ENTERING DETAILS FOR THE CHANNELID', $scope.ch_id)
        if(e.which == 13){           
            // Insert into DB, the information about the channel here
        }
    });
```

This code sample should get you started, I simply remove all existing 'keydown' event handlers (attached from previous channels) before attaching a new event handler for the current channel.